# Zend Framework 2 Session

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-session

Full example of how to use Zend Framework 2 Session in Controllers, and display the session variable to the view (.phtml).

Comment: Have you tried google.com?

Comment: there are just parts of using Zend Session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the links below would be a good starting point.

Links:

[Using Sessions in Zend Framework 2](http://codingexplained.com/coding/php/zend-framework/using-sessions-in-zend-framework-2)

[Using Sessions In Zend Framework 2 – Part 1](http://www.masterzendframework.com/sessions/using-sessions-in-zend-framework-2-part-1)

[Session Container](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.session.container.html)

update:
in your view action inside a controller add them in the ViewModel.

```
        //session 
        $session = new Container('somecontainer');
        $poster = $session->somename;//$session->somename holds data set from another action

        $view = new ViewModel(array(
            'poster' => $poster,

        ));
        return $view;
```

and inside the view depending on the type of the variable you use it

```
echo $poster;//will echo the session message.
```

Comment: Already got through this links.But how to use session variables in view files?

Comment: I will implement this type and also found some books. Will search also through them.